# How to handle a jank (non-uniform) spritesheet in Unity 2D

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm trying to rip the among us textures into Unity, but I'm having trouble with the spritesheet for crewmate animations like walking, venting, idle, etc.

Here's the spritesheet I'm talking about: https://github.com/Overload02/among-us-assets/blob/main/Players/Player-sharedassets0.assets-55.png

You can see it is not consistent at all, making a uniform square or rectangle cut impossible.

What I tried originally is just creating all the boxes manually, but this looks terrible.

How does one handle this elagently?

Comment: Never had a problem with non identical sized sprites.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use each sprite as a seperate image instead of a spritesheet. then you could edit the edges of each one seperately.